# Mongodb inconsistent implicit and/or

Tags: mongodb

I'm getting inconsistent results when I want mongo to AND two conditions. When I explicitly $and them, all is good.

```
> db.test.insert({t:ISODate("2014-03-28")})
> db.test.find({t:ISODate("2014-03-28")})
{ "t" : ISODate("2014-03-28T00:00:00Z") }
```

Isolated conditionals, all good:

```
> db.test.find({t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-27")}})
> db.test.find({t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-27")}})
{ "t" : ISODate("2014-03-28T00:00:00Z") }
> db.test.find({t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-29")}})
> db.test.find({t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-29")}})
{ "t" : ISODate("2014-03-28T00:00:00Z") }
```

These work as you would expect from an implicit "and":

```
> db.test.find({t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-27")},t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-27")}})
> db.test.find({t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-29")},t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-29")}})
> db.test.find({t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-27")},t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-29")}})
{ "t" : ISODate("2014-03-28T00:00:00Z") }
> db.test.find({t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-29")},t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-27")}})
{ "t" : ISODate("2014-03-28T00:00:00Z") }
```

However, these ones behave like "or":

```
> db.test.find({t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-27")},t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-27")}})
{ "t" : ISODate("2014-03-28T00:00:00Z") }
> db.test.find({t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-29")},t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-29")}})
{ "t" : ISODate("2014-03-28T00:00:00Z") }
```

And everything works as expected, regardless the order, with explicit "$and""

```
> db.test.find({"$and": [{t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-27")}},{t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-27")}}]})
> db.test.find({"$and": [{t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-27")}},{t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-27")}}]})
> db.test.find({"$and": [{t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-29")}},{t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-29")}}]})
> db.test.find({"$and": [{t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-29")}},{t:{"$gte":ISODate("2014-03-29")}}]})
```

Any ideas of what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `behave like "or"` case, what's actually going on is that you can only have one key per object with the same name, so only the second `t` value is used.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on @JohnnyHK:

```
db.test.find({t:{"$lte":ISODate("2014-03-29"), "$gte":ISODate("2014-03-27")}})
```

Is the right way to do it